# XPath, flat hierarchy and stop condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, flat

I need to construct Start objects from very bad XML. I made SAX parser for one case but it's messy and I would like to try XPath.

I have following XML:

```
<doc>
    <start/>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>

    <start/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>

    <start/>
    <b/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>

</doc>
```

However I would much more like this document (which I don't have):

```
<doc>
    <start>
        <a/>
        <b/>
        <item/>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    <start/>

    <start>
        <item/>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    <start/>

    <start>
        <b/>
        <item/>
        <item/>
       <item/>
    <start/>

</doc>
```

Suppose please that I have 2nd "start" node object (from 1st XML example). Now I'd like to get "a" and "b" elements directly following this node. However if I make relative query from this node (with following-sibling) for "b" node I will get node under 3rd start node. Is it possible to say "find node X following this node but stop on node Y (return null)" ?

I know I can use "|" to OR multiple queries but this is not what I want (though it could possibly solve my problem too).

Thank you.

Comment: Also by "directly following" I don't mean immediately after current node but somewhere before next "start" node.

Comment: Not clear if you want that output or just an XPath selection. In the former case you should use XSLT to transform your input.

Answer (score 4):

If you go with XSLT 1.0 you can also group adjacent siblings by using a key `xsl:key`, thus simplifying XPath expressions:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k_adjChild"
        match="/*/*[not(self::start)]"
        use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::start[1])"
        />

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <doc>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="start"/>
        </doc>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="start">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('k_adjChild', generate-id())" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the context is a particular `<start>` element, this XPath will select all of the nodes between the current `<start>` and the following `<start>`.

```
following-sibling::node()[not(self::start)]
                         [generate-id(preceding-sibling::start[1]) 
                           = generate-id(current())]
```

This XSLT applies that XPath in order to group the content by the `<start>` elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|start" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--for each start element, copy it,
        apply templates for it's attributes(in case any exist)
        and for nodes() that are following-siblings
        who's first preceeding-sibling is this start element-->
    <xsl:template match="start">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*
                | following-sibling::node()[not(self::start)]
                    [generate-id(preceding-sibling::start[1]) 
                      = generate-id(current())]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 just note that `generate-id()` is not an XPath function. You can use that kind of XPath expression only in a transform.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input XML is in file `in.xml` this XQuery script does what you want:

```
(:
  This library function can be found here:
  http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_index-of-node.html
:)
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"; 
declare function functx:index-of-node($nodes as node()* ,
$nodeToFind as node() )  as xs:integer* 
{     
  for $seq in (1 to count($nodes))
  return $seq[$nodes[$seq] is $nodeToFind]
};

(:
  Recursively calculate the start elements with the other elements between
  as childs.
  Take the first two indices of $positions and create a start element
  with the elements of $elements with positions between these two indices.
  Then remove the first index of $position and do the recursive call.
  Input:
    $positions: Sequence with start element indices (belongs to $elements)
    $elements: Element sequence
  Output:
    Sequence of start elements with child elements
:)
declare function local:partition($positions as xs:integer*, 
    $elements as element()*) as element()* 
{
  let $len := count($positions)
  return
    if($len gt 1)
    then (
      let $first := $positions[1]
      let $second := $positions[2]
      let $rest := subsequence($positions, 2)
      return
        ( element start
          {
            subsequence($elements, $first + 1, $second - $first - 1)
          },
          local:partition($rest, $elements)
        )
    ) 
    else if($len eq 1)
    then (
          element start
          {
            subsequence($elements, $positions[1] + 1)
          }
    )
    else () 
};

(: Input document :)
let $input-doc := doc('in.xml')

(: Sequence of all child elements of root element doc :)
let $childs := $input-doc/doc/node()[. instance of element()]

(: Sequence with the indices of the start elements in $childs :)
let $positions := for $s in $input-doc/doc/start 
                  return functx:index-of-node($childs, $s)

return 
  <doc>
  {
    local:partition($positions, $childs)
  }
  </doc>
```

The output is:

```
<doc>
  <start>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
  </start>
  <start>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
  </start>
  <start>
    <b/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
  </start>
</doc>
```

Testet with [XQilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage) but every other XQuery processor should produce the same result.